# SQL query that returns the best match (row that has the most matching columns)

Tags: php, sql

My database looks like this:

```
id | A | B | C | D
```

and for each letter, there's a random value between 0 and 3.

These values change for each ID.

How can i select the row that has the most matching columns, even if it is not a perfect match?

(This shows exactly what i mean:)

http://prnt.sc/elkyzn

I hope this picture helps,
I need to create a 15 questions quiz that matches a dog for you.
each question of the 15 returns a value from 0 to 3, and then there are 11 yes or no questions (0 = no and 1 = yes)

at the end of the quiz, i get something like this: (changes from pereson to person) 0-3, 0-4, 0-2, 0-2, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1.

and i need to collect these values and get the best match, the dog that has the most matching columns.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is rather unclear.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: You'll probably be looking at `select id from tablename order by sum((A=1) + (B=1) + (C=1) + (D=1)) desc limit 1` (find row with most 1s, in this example)

Comment: `How can i select the row that has the most matching columns` If one row have "0" in all columns, and another row have "1" in all columns, then which one row do you want to select ? both ?

Comment: http://prnt.sc/elkyzn


I hope this picture helps,
I need to create a 15 questions quiz that matches a dog for you.
each question of the 15 returns a value from 0 to 3, and then there are 11 yes or no questions (0 = no and 1 = yes)


in the end of the quiz, i get something like this: (changes from pereson to person) 0-3, 0-4, 0-2, 0-2, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1.


and i need to collect these values and get the best match, the dog that has the most matching columns.

hope i was clear this time, and thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to come with a scoring system because you aren't looking for an exact match. An example of an idea would be.

Select  Id from 
{
Select A -B, A-C, A-D, B-C, B-D, C-D, id
From table
}  Outer
Where (use some logic here to determine what you think fits)

One idea is to sum up all the differences from the inner query. But, that could give false results if you have one that's really big and one that real small.

You could also do AVG of the sum of all of the differences.

The other thing you could do is to order by columns in the inner query where the difference is 0. Order by case when 0 else 1 end.

Or a combination.

It really depends on what exactly your trying to get

Comment: http://prnt.sc/elkyzn

I hope this picture helps,
I need to create a 15 questions quiz that matches a dog for you.
each question of the 15 returns a value from 0 to 3, and then there are 11 yes or no questions (0 = no and 1 = yes)

at the end of the quiz, i get something like this: (changes from pereson to person) 0-3, 0-4, 0-2, 0-2, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1, 0/1.

and i need to collect these values and get the best match, the dog that has the most matching columns.

hope i explained myself better, and thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

you can select all the elements that have the sum of the columns the same as the sum from input
then you can foreach through them and see the matches, and keep a variable "$best" which you will updated when you fill find an element with more matches

Comment: actually, if you won'y have thousands of entries in your database you can fetch all the data and simply keep that $best

Comment: what do you mean lessan?

Comment: that thing with the sum, now i realised its not a good ideea, because you may have cases when only one column is matched, so you have to select all the entries with column_sum<=input_sum but considering how few elements this eliminates, its not worth, i think its faster to simply select all of your elements and foreach through them looking for matches

Comment: but that depends on how many entries you can have in your database, how many columns etc. for like 1500 elements with 4 columns, the fastest way would be to simply select all the data

Comment: I hope that you saw that i updated the main thread with more detail, including my database.

i still dont get it - if i did that, how could i store the data in a var? i'd have to check for each column which row matches it, and then display the row that was returned the most?

could you give me a code example for the first 2 columns? http://prnt.sc/elkyzn

thanks again for answering